# TestNG Reporter log messages that show when you click on a test method in the HTML report

Tags: java, testing, testng

When I use `Reporter.log()` the messages are displayed in the `Reporter output` section of the HTML report.

I would like to be able to show these messages under each test that I click in the `Results` section:

[image]

How can I do that?